# Oversized "implies" arrow tip in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am switching all of the arrow tips in `tikzcd` from the default ones to `angle 45` in the tikz `arrows` library. When I attempt to apply it to the double-arrows using `tikzcd implies/.tip`, the tip of the arrow appears to be overly large. How can I resize the tip so that it is of the same size as the tip of the `to` arrows?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzcdset{%
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>=angle 45},
tikzcd implies/.tip={>}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below}] \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D}] & 
B \arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to creat such style? If you comment the lines containing the style you will get the correct arrow tip for `Rightarrow`

Comment: @Luis Turcio It's just a personal preference. Because the default ```implies``` tips are curvy, I think they do not look good with the straight edges of ```angle 45```.

Comment: Sort of known limitation, https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/issues/1.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the specific line `tikzcd implies/.tip={Implies}` instead of `tikzcd implies/.tip={>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzcdset{%
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>=angle 45},
tikzcd implies/.tip={Implies}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below}] \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D}] & 
B \arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

In fact you will have the correct tips for **implies**. Here there is the snapshot:

[image]

If you, one day, to use an old package called `xy`, with the option `2cell`, you will obtain this (I have used the parameter `<5>` to increase the arcs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ A\rtwocell<5> &B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am using ```implies/.tip={>}``` because I want to use ```angle 45``` for the ```implies``` tips specifically, otherwise ```tikzcd implies/.tip={Implies}``` seems to be the default option, which is not required inside of ```\tikzcdset```.

Comment: @FR09 Oh, hi. Don't worry if I have not given a true help. I not thing that it is possible to reproduce the angle 45 for the implies. I have seen also the option of implies here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3S9QwZMp-NcJ:ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex+&cd=4&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it and I not see the possibility to have the correct `.tip={>}`. Probably that you can create a macro with a specific implies with the same tips of the bend: see this link https://latexdraw.com/exploring-tikz-arrows/  using \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

Answer (score 1):

To get straight lines in the arrow tips I suggest to use `Straight Barb` tips. With the defaults they look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzcdset{%
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>={Straight Barb}},
tikzcd implies/.tip={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below}] \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D}] & 
B \arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you prefer the 45 degrees of the tip you can add the `angle` key as follows

```
diagrams={>={Straight Barb[angle=45:4pt]}},
```

there are more keys to control the look of the tip, like `width` or `length`

**Edit**

After a quick read of the [tikz/pgf manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), in section 16.4.3 you can see a quick "fix" for the overlapping problem of the tip (note the `.` added to both tips), I also make the angle tips equal to 45 degrees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{%
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>={.Straight Barb[angle=45:4pt]}},
tikzcd implies/.tip={.Straight Barb[angle=45:6pt]}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below}] \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D}] & 
B \arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

With this separation between the line and the tip you can also avoid the problem of the tip at 45 degrees not centered with respect to the line.

[image]

Comment: Hi; I have read your answer and I have appreciated it. For my humblest opinion like I thought give a strange and unusual effect for the tip of implies. +1

Comment: Yes, I see the tip not placed at the very end. At the moment I am not sure how to make that correction. In a moment I will read tikz documentation, but any correction is welcome

Comment: I think that the tip with the tickness of the implies give a ugly impact with tikzcd implies/.tip={.Straight Barb[angle=45:6pt]}.

Comment: Then, the only possibility I can think is to create an arrow style from scratch

Comment: No :-) just if you can decrease the distance of the > with the = sign, it is better.